# Count the number strings in a column according to the value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. The first one is the big data frame with 2000 samples, it has all sort of informations about patiens like age, gender, therapy...

The second data frame is a summarized version of the first. Here is subsamples of the two data frames:

The first - here I'm presenting just the first few rows. Overall I have about 10 datasets:

```
structure(list(dataset = c("data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "dataset2", "dataset2", "dataset2", "dataset2", 
"Data_3", "Data_3"), samples = c("PtX1", "PtZ10", "PtZ101", 
"PtX103", "Pt10T6", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24"), Gender = c("male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "male"), treatment = c("Treatment1", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", 
"Treatment1 + Treatment3", "Treatment3", "Treatment1", "Treatment3", "Treatment2", "Treatment2 + Treatment3", 
"Treatment1")), row.names = c("PtX1", "PtZ10", "PtZ101", "PtX103", 
"Pt10T6", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24"), class = "data.frame")
```

And `df2` :

```
structure(list(Articles = c("data1", "dataset2", "Data_3"), male = c(25L, 137L, 29L), female = c(24L, 
44L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L))
```

You can see for example, `df2` counts how many males and females there are for each data set, according to `df1`. (The males and females you see here are the real values)

Now I want count the treatments. Some data sets use different treatments in their samples. I have 3 types of treatment and a combination between two of them, so overall 4 values.

What I want is **4** new columns in `df2`, each treatment gets a column.

So for example: In `df2`, `dataset2` would have 1 of `Treatment1`, 1 of `Treatment2`, and 2 of `Treatment3`. The column `Treatment1 + Treatment3` will be 0 since there no such observation in `df1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df2)[dcast(setDT(df1)[grepl("+", treatment, fixed = TRUE),
  treatment := "Combination"], dataset ~ treatment, length), 
    on = .(Articles = dataset)]
```

-output

```
   Articles male female Combination Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
1:   Data_3   29     15           1          1          0          0
2:    data1   25     24           1          2          1          0
3: dataset2  137     44           0          1          1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr/tidyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

structure(list(dataset = c("data1", "data1", "data1", 
"data1", "dataset2", "dataset2", "dataset2", "dataset2", 
"Data_3", "Data_3"), samples = c("PtX1", "PtZ10", "PtZ101", 
"PtX103", "Pt10T6", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24"), Gender = c("male", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "female", "female", "male", 
"male", "male"), treatment = c("Treatment1", "Treatment1", "Treatment2", 
"Treatment1 + Treatment3", "Treatment3", "Treatment1", "Treatment3", "Treatment2", "Treatment2 + Treatment3", 
"Treatment1")), row.names = c("PtX1", "PtZ10", "PtZ101", "PtX103", 
"Pt10T6", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", "Pt24"), class = "data.frame") %>%
group_by(dataset, treatment) %>% # remove. `dataset` if you want to summarize across all your datasets
summarise(tcount = n()) %>%
ungroup() %>%
pivot_wider(values_from = tcount, names_from = treatment, 
values_fill = 0)
```

It is returning the following :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  dataset  Treatment1 `Treatment2 + Tre~ `Treatment1 + Tr~ Treatment2 Treatment3
  <chr>         <int>              <int>             <int>      <int>      <int>
1 Data_3            1                  1                 0          0          0
2 data1             2                  0                 1          1          0
3 dataset2          1                  0                 0          1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `summarise` your `df1`, then join them together. Since you only want four new columns, any `treatment` group with a plus symbol `+` would be classified as `Combination`.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df2, 
          df1 %>% 
            mutate(treatment = ifelse(grepl("\\+", treatment), "Combination", treatment)) %>% 
            group_by(dataset, treatment) %>% 
            summarize(n = n()) %>% 
            pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = n, values_fill = 0),
          by = c("Articles"  = "dataset"))
  

  Articles male female Combination Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
1    data1   25     24           1          2          1          0
2 dataset2  137     44           0          1          1          2
3   Data_3   29     15           1          1          0          0
```